# Alternative to xdotool which is already installed on Ubuntu

Tags: scripts, software-recommendation, xdotool, restricted

I need to use xdotool to quickly automate some click at specific locations of my screen. I could use the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 0.5
xdotool click 200 150
sleep 0.5
xdotool click 200 175
sleep 0.5
xdotool click 1050 150
sleep 0.5
xdotool click 1350 450
sleep 0.5
xdotool click 1100 150
```

And it would work fine. However, `xdotool` is not installed on the machine I'm using, and I do not have root access. I cannot install it locally because the `X11/extensions/XTest.h` library is not present. What are my options?

Comment: Probably you could use some of the Gtk libraries for Python, I recall there's ways to move cursor, though not sure about clicking.

Comment: There's the `pyautogui` module, see https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/ – but of course that's far from being preinstalled. May I ask why you want to get control over the mouse on a system where you don't even have root access?

Comment: @dessert oh it’s a virtual machine provided by my university. I remotely connect to it, but one of the tasks I have to do is click the following buttons in order: Compile, Load, Reset, Clear, Run. Doing that every time I change the code is annoying!

Comment: And there is no CLI for whatever program you need to run there? Are you sure? How do you connect by the way? Maybe there's a way to control the mouse remotely? Btw, please always add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) using the [formatting tools](https://$SITEURL$/help/formatting) rather than using comments.

Comment: @dessert that information is not critical and makes the question overly specific. I know that there might be ways around this but I’m specifically asking for alternatives to xdotool. I have a workaround - controlling the mouse on the local machine but this isn’t perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile xdotool statically and copy it to that machine.

Alternatively you can copy the dynamically linked binary and see if the libraries resolve.

Answer (score 0):

If I'd seen this question in 2017, I'd've urged you to just *find* the `XTest.h` header, rather than heading down some other avenue. Fixing some missing headers is probably easier than anything else suggested here, assuming that was the *only* problem.

***tl;dr**: `sudo apt install libxtst-dev`*

However, in 2024, for Debian and Ubuntu (and derivatives), `xdootool` should be available in the distro repositories. In Ubuntu, you'll need to enable the `universe` respository, which many distros do by default.

If you *must* install from source, for some reason, `apt build-dep xdotool` will help immensely. It installs all the build-time dependencies for a given source package. The only downside is the package must exist in the Debian/Ubuntu repositories for `build-dep` to know what to do.

When a particular software package *does* exist in the Debian/Ubuntu repositories (even as an older version), this alleviates the burden of having to identify which headers (`-dev` packages) and other libraries need to be installed to build from source.

```
$ apt-get --dry-run build-dep xdotool | grep Inst
Inst libllvm14 (1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
[…snip…]
Inst openbox (3.6.1-10 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Inst xserver-common [2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5] (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [all])
Inst xterm (372-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Inst xvfb (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Inst dh-exec (0.23.4build2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
```

In truth, you may end up with some other cruft—packages only "required" in the sense that they were needed for testing and packaging, like `openbox` through `dh-exev` in the output above—but at least it's alleviating the guesswork. I would say **in some cases** you can uninstall those packages later with a command like this:

```bash
apt-get --dry-run build-dep THE_PACKAGE_NAME \
  | awk '$1=="Inst"{print $2}' \
  | xargs sudo apt remove
```

…but I wouldn't recommend blindly doing that for the particular case of `xdootool`, otherwise you'll break your system.

Let's say I hadn't known about `apt build-dep`, though. One can always use [`apt-file`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptFile)* to help locate the package that would contain that missing header:

```
$ apt-file search XTest.h
libbcprov-java-doc: /usr/share/doc/libbcprov-java/api/org/bouncycastle/crypto/test/EAXTest.html
libbcprov-java-doc: /usr/share/doc/libbcprov-java/api/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/PKIXTest.html
libjna-java-doc: /usr/share/doc/libjna-java/api/com/sun/jna/platform/unix/X11.XTest.html
libxtst-dev: /usr/include/X11/extensions/XTest.h
```

The answer in this case is `sudo apt install libxtst-dev`.

On a pretty new install of elementary OS 7 (based on Ubuntu 22.04), where I had already installed `build-essential` and `elementary-sdk`, I had no issue cloning the current `master` branch of [jordansissel/xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) from GitHub, and running `make` in the source directory. Your mileage may vary, though.

Hope that helps (someone)!

---

*Expect this issue [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503481/why-does-apt-file-report-the-cache-is-empty-even-after-running-apt-file-updat) the first time you try to use `apt-file search`, though; you may just need to run an extra `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt-file update` is all.